# Subtracting time in a Python Alarm Clock

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, clock, alarm

I am currently writing an Alarm Clock scipt in Python for a Raspberry Pi project. I need help with parsing the hours and minutes from both the current time and alarm time and converting them to seconds so that I can subtract current time from alarm time.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your current code attempt and your question/problem? Otherwise, this is an open-ended question on design and not really appropriate for SO.

Comment: I've just seen your edit and I believe my answer is fitting for the issue. Do you need any more help?

Comment: Thank you! I think that should solve my issue, I'll try it out now :)

Comment: @Maximus If my answer indeed helped you please accept it. Otherwise I'll gladly help with any more issues you have :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to use datetime in python.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import time
format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
currTime = dt.now()
alarmTime = dt.strptime('2017-12-25 08:00:00', format); 
print('current time:\t', currTime)
print('alarm time:\t', alarmTime)
currTimeUnix = time.mktime(currTime.timetuple())
alarmTimeUnix = time.mktime(alarmTime.timetuple())
diff = alarmTimeUnix - currTimeUnix
print('seconds diff: \t', diff)
```

The output will be:

```
current time:    2017-12-24 22:40:30.842519
alarm time:      2017-12-25 08:00:00
seconds diff:    33570.0
```

Sleep example:

```
s = 3;
print(dt.now())
time.sleep(s)
print('I\'ve slept for', s, 'seconds')
print(dt.now())
```

Will result in:

```
2017-12-24 22:44:24.275121
I've slept for 3 seconds
2017-12-24 22:44:27.276324
```